# PHPTAL replace but keep certain attributes?

Tags: php, template-tal, phptal

Is it possible to do a `tal:replace="whatever"` but maintain certain attributes of the element/tag?

For example, if you have the following:

```
<input type='text' value='test' name='hello' class='specialClass' tal:replace="customInput"/>
```

Is it possible to have your `customInput` replace the current input but somehow also have the `specialClass` class as well?

I can't tell if PHPTAL allows things like this or if I need to override some PHPTAL method for replacing...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `tal:replace` completely replaces the element with text, so there is nothing to put these attributes on.

Attributes are preserved with `tal:content`.

In case of `<input>`, you'd rather use `value="${customValue}"` or `tal:attributes="value customValue"`.

PHPTAL doesn't parse any markup at run time, so if you have something that generates `<input>`'s HTML dynamically for you, then you need to modify that code yourself.